# Partial Views with Local Variable Scope In CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have something like the following code in one of my views:

```
<?php $this->load->view('_validation_error', array('errors' => $errors, 'field' => 'address_1', 'is_required' => true)); ?>

... some html ...

<?php $this->load->view('_validation_error', array('errors' => $errors, 'field' => 'address_2')); ?>
```

This allows me to use `$errors`, `$field` and `$is_required` in the partial. This is good, although what's happening here is that if I don't supply the 'is_required' value on subsequent calls to the partial, it's getting set to what the last value was (true in this case).

I could just put the value in every time but I was hoping to have it behave like an optional parameter to a function. Is there any functionality in CodeIgniter that allows partials to have their own local variable scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sweet! Never mind, I think I figured out a hack to get around it.

instead of going:

```
<?php $this->load->view('_validation_error', array('errors' => $errors, 'field' => 'address_1', 'is_required' => true)); ?>
```

I can go:

```
<?php $this->load->view('_validation_error', array('data' => array('errors' => $errors, 'field' => 'address_1', 'is_required' => true))); ?>
```

That way I have access to `$data['errors']`, `$data['field']` and `$data['is_required']`.

That way any values not passed in are overwritten and by default are optional.

:)